# Show that the $D_{3h}$ prism is given by the direct product $D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, dihedral-groups, direct-product

I have some questions regarding the notation and solution to the following problem involving the direct product:

> The diagram below shows the symmetry operations of an equilateral right triangular prism. The elements of $D_3$ are the identity $E$, $(\mathrm{a})$ the rotations $C_3$ and ${C_3}^2$, and $(\mathrm{b})$ the vertical reflection planes $\sigma_{v,1}$, $\sigma_{v,2}$, and $\sigma_{v,3}$, and those of $C_s$ are the identity $E$ and $(\mathrm{c})$ a horizontal reflection plane $\sigma_h$ midway between the two horizontal faces of the prism.
> [image: Prisms]
> Show that the group $D_{3h}$ prism is given by the direct product $$D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s$$
> where $C_s=\{E, \sigma_h\}$

My first question is regarding the notation, according to this article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20in%20group,usually%20denoted%20G%20%C3%97%20H.) for the direct product of two groups, the correct notation is actually $D_{3h}=D_3 \oplus C_s$ and *not* $D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s$. This is confusing me as I thought the '$\oplus$' was the notation reserved for the **direct sum**. Why then the inconsistency for the notation?

Looking across the literature, "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" by Joseph A Gallian, 10th edition, page 172 uses $\oplus$, yet "Group Theory - Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter", by Dresselhaus, 2008, page 101 uses $\otimes$ as does "Group Theory in Physics" by Wu-Ki Tung, 1985, page 25. Yet other books such as "Applications of Group Theory in Quantum Mechanics" by Petrashen and Trifonov, published in 2009 on page 49 use a regular "$\times$". Due to this I'm very confused which notation to use.

---

On to the question itself, using the definition from my notes:

> **DEFINITION** $1.2.$ A **direct product** of two groups $H$ and $K$, denoted as $H \otimes K$, is deﬁned as the set of all distinct ordered pairs $(h, k)$, where $h$ is an element of $H$ and $k$ is an element of $K$, with the binary composition law
> $$(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2) \equiv (h_1h_2,k_1k_2),$$
> determined by the composition rules within $H$ and $K$. This direct product, also known as the **external product**, satisﬁes the group axioms.

Applying the procedure outlined above to the 2 groups I find that,

$$D_{3h}=D_3\otimes C_s =\left(E, C_3, {C_3}^2, \sigma_{v,1}, \sigma_{v,2}, \sigma_{v,3}\right)\left(E, \sigma_h\right)$$
$$=\left(E, C_3, {C_3}^2, \sigma_{v,1}, \sigma_{v,2}, \sigma_{v,3}, \sigma_h, C_3\sigma_h,{C_3}^2\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,1}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,2}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,3}\sigma_h\right)\tag{1}$$

The problem with this equation is that I don't know what the elements of $D_{3h}$ are, so I followed the prescription laid out by my notes but how does this prove that $D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s$?

Here is the author's solution:

> The group $D_3$ of the top and bottom faces has elements $$D_3=\{E, C_3, {C_3}^2, \sigma_{v,1}, \sigma_{v,2}, \sigma_{v,3}\}$$
> The prism has an additional symmetry operation, a horizontal reflection plane $\sigma_h$, resulting from the equivalence of the top and bottom faces. The associated group is $C_s = \{E, \sigma_h\}$. Since $\sigma_h$ operates on vertical coordinates, and the elements of $D_3$ operate on horizontal coordinates, the elements of $C_s$ and $D_3$ commute. Hence, the group of the prism, which is
> denoted as $D_{3h}$, is
> $$D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s.$$

---

Again, this solution doesn't really seem to 'prove' that $D_{3h}=D_3 \otimes C_s$, to me the author has just given a handwaving argument and I'm left confused.

So to summarize, is there a way to be more formal about this proof (like what I was trying to do in equation $(1)$), ie. utilizing the recipe given, that $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1h_2,k_1k_2)$?

Comment: @Skynet - in the definition of the "direct product" $H\otimes K$ of two groups: You say it is the "set of distinct ordered pairs" $(h,k)$ with $h\in H,k\in K$. Why do you use the words "distinct" and "ordered"? The two groups $H \neq K$ are distinct, hence to speak of distinct elements and ordered pair does not make much sense.

Comment: @hm2020 Hi there, I did not choose those words, they are simply the words used in the definition given by my notes (which I was told to typeset properly). The original images are in the revision history. In fact, the very question you are asking is my question also, these words you mention confuse me. I really don't know what is meant by "distinct" and "ordered", and part of this question is aimed at trying to address the meaning of those words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it might be useful to read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450766/the-confusing-nature-of-direct-sum-for-finite-abelian-groups) to see what is usually meant by direct sum and direct products of groups. In particular, you'll see that finite direct sums are the same as finite direct products.

Now, to answer your first question, Wikipedia rightly states that in the case of *abelian* groups the (finite) direct product is sometimes referred to as the direct sum, and denoted by $\oplus$. If you want an explanation for the notation, it has to do with the properties of the category $\operatorname{Ab}$ of abelian groups, i.e. the "collection" of all abelian groups and homomorphisms thereof. In $\operatorname{Ab}$, finite direct sums/products correspond to both the categorical concept of coproduct and that of product (it turns out that this seemingly innocuous formal property of $\operatorname{Ab}$ can be abstracted to more complicated categories, which by virtue of this formal similarity behave something like $\operatorname{Ab}$, an observation of extreme importance in modern mathematics), thus they are denoted the same. In the case of general groups (i.e. not necessarily abelian), this is no longer true (direct products still correspond to products, but coproducts correspond rather to the free product of groups), thus the direct product of groups is usually denoted with $\times$ (it is still a different concept that the direct sum $\oplus$, even if they coincide for finitely many terms).

As for $\otimes$, I don't think it is standard in mathematics to denote the direct product of groups with that symbol (which is reserved for other things); I suspect those books where you found such a notation reserve $\times$ for something else and use $\otimes$ to avoid confusion. Moreover, they seem to be written by physicists (I'm not being snarky here, it's just that physicists are interested in different things and might use different notations from mathematicians).

Now we come to your actual question. I agree that the solution given is not necessarily very clear as to why $D_{3h}$ is exactly the same as $D_3\times C_s$, but it has the right ideas to solve the problem. You do agree that $D_3\times C_s$ is a subgroup of $D_{3h}$, considering what the solution says? If you do (and I believe the solution is clear enough on this, but feel free to ask for clarifications), we just need to show that any element of $D_{3h}$, i.e. any symmetry of the prism, is an element of $D_3\times C_s$, i.e. a symmetry of the triangle plus possibly a reflection that swaps the two triangular faces. But this is clear: a symmetry of the prism is determined by whether it exchanges the two triangular faces and by how it exchanges the vertical edges (by virtue of symmetries being "rigid": they do not change angles and length; you might feel the need to make this more precise, which is annoying but not difficult), thus the cardinality of $D_{3h}$ is the same as the cardinality of its subgroup $D_3\times C_s$, which means they are the same.

Edit: let me add something more. The "recipe" for the group operation in a direct product of groups $H\times K$ is really just telling you that elements of the two factors (identified as pairs $(a,E)$ or $(E,b)$ in the product, for $a\in H$ and $b\in K$) are somehow independent of each other, i.e. they commute, and generate the group. The direct product $H\times K$ is uniquely determined by this property (you might want to think about why this is true: if any other group had this property it would be easy to find an isomorphism with $H\times K$). Thus, whenever you have two subgroups of a group with the elements of one commuting with those of the other, you can consider a bigger subgroup, the direct product of the two subgroups with the operation described.

Comment: Btw, feel free to ask for clarification. I'd be happy to help (or rather, try to help) if you have any further question or doubt.

Comment: My apologies for this late response, due to work I have been too busy to answer until now. I will offer the bounty now as time is running out. But I just have two questions regarding your answer if that's okay? You write that "You do agree that $D_3\times C_s$ is a subgroup of $D_{3h}$, considering what the solution says?" This part I don't agree with, in fact, it was my understanding that $D_3\times C_s$ represents the *whole* group of $D_{3h}$. Secondly, you mention that "the cardinality of $D_{3h}$ is the same as the cardinality of its subgroup $D_3\times C_s$". If that is ......

Comment: true then $\lvert D_{3h}\rvert=6$ means equation $(1)$ must have 6 elements and not 12 as I wrote here - $(E, C_3, {C_3}^2, \sigma_{v,1}, \sigma_{v,2}, \sigma_{v,3}, \sigma_h, C_3\sigma_h,{C_3}^2\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,1}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,2}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,3}\sigma_h)$, 
but this can only be true if the first 6 elements of $(1)$ are identical to the *next* 6 respective elements $E, C_3, {C_3}^2, \sigma_{v,1}, \sigma_{v,2}, \sigma_{v,3} = \sigma_h, C_3\sigma_h,{C_3}^2\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,1}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,2}\sigma_h,\sigma_{v,3}\sigma_h$, ie. $E=\sigma_h\,, C_3=C_3\sigma_h$ .....

Comment: and so on up to $\sigma_{v,3}=\sigma_{v,3}\sigma_h$. But how can say, $C_3=C_3\sigma_h$ for example, this doesn't make any sense to me? Many thanks for your answer, and again, I'm sorry for such a late reply. Congrats on the bounty!

Comment: No need to be sorry! With my comments I wasn't exhorting you to respond, I was just wondering whether my answer was clear. Tomorrow I might edit my answer to address your questions, for now I'll respond quickly (so if there is something else to clear up, just ask).

Comment: For your first question: sure, $D_3\times C_s$ is the whole $D_{3h}$. When we say subgroup in mathematics, we usually don't mean a subgroup strictly smaller than the whole group (if that's what we need we call it a *proper* subgroup). [cont]

Comment: In this case it is easy to see that there is a subgroup of the symmetry group of the prism which can be described as $D_3\times C_s$: this is just the observation that pairs $(a,b)$, for $a$ a symmetry of the triangle and $b$ either the identity or $\sigma_h$, describe symmetries of the prism, and moreover the set of pairs (a,b) form a group with operation given by using the operation of $D_3$ on the first element and of $C_s$ on the second (exactly the operation presecribed in the definition of the direct product).

Comment: Now that we now that $D_3\times C_s$ is a (not necessarily proper!) subgroup of $D_{3h}$, which was correctly shown in the author's solution, we want to prove that it is indeed the whole $D_{3h}$, which instead in that solution was just left implicit.

Comment: This is were my counting the number of symmetries of the prism comes to the rescue: we know that $D_3\times C_s$ has $12$ elements and we counted that $D_{3h}$ also does (maybe I should have explained this more clearly: a symmetry is determined by whether it exchanges the triangular faces, 2 possibilities, and how it exchanges the vertical edges, 6 possibilities, thus there are 12 possible symmetries). Thus $D_3\times C_s$ is *not* a proper subgroup, it is the whole $D_{3h}$. I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, if I've understood you correctly then $\lvert D_3\rvert \times \lvert C_{s}\rvert=6\times 2=\lvert D_{3h}\rvert=12$, so does this mean that what I wrote in equation $(1)$ is correct? The only other question that remains is what I wrote in an earlier comment, namely, what is meant by $C_3\sigma_h$ in $(1)$ for example? Or, put another way, how can a 120-degree rotation followed by a horizontal reflection be distinct from the other elements of $D_3$? Sorry if the question is a bit vague.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is correct (usually we denote elements in the product as pairs $(a,b)$, but that's just notation, the twelve elements of the direct product are essentially those you wrote down)! The symmetry $(C_3,\sigma_h)$ is a rotation plus a horizontal reflection, and it is distinct from any element of the form $(a,E)$ for $a\in D_3$ precisely because it exchanges the triangular faces of the prism, while the elements $(a,E)$ don't.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer and explanations, I appreciate your time. I was just a bit disappointed (and confused) why the solution given did not state equation $(1)$ as I did. The solution give seems to be lacking the right formalism and is too heuristic. But I won't ask any more questions about this as I think I've already asked enough. Best regards and thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, sorry to resurrect the discussion, but I am just curious about one thing. You write that "usually we denote elements in the product as pairs $(a,b)$", but what would eqn $(1)$ look like if written as 'pairs'?

Comment: No problem! Well, there are 12 elements at the end of that equation, and 12 possible pairs $(a,b)$ for $a\in D_3$ and $b\in C_s$, so it will look very similar: there's a very easy translation from what you wrote to the correct notation. Btw, I understand that formalism can be tricky to grasp and as a beginner it's ok to demand precision, but I'm gonna tell you this anyway: rigor in mathematics is obviously fundamental, but you shouldn't ever let it hinder your understanding. In this case, it's important that you understand how to work with products, but the idea of the proof is what matters.